# python Each section below is a function that must implement, make sure the function's names and parameters match the documentation (Copy-Paste)

Tags: python-3.x

`def productSum(x: int, y: int, z: int) -> int`

This function should return:

1. The product of x and y, if the product of x and y is less than z.
2. Else it should return the sum of x and y, if the product of x and y is greater than or equal to z.

Example 1:
`x = 5, y = 2, z = 9`

Output: `7 = 5 + 2` because `5 * 2 > 9`

Example 2:
`x = 4, y = 3, z = 19`

Output: `12 = 4 * 3` because `4 * 3 < 19`

`def functionSolver(function: callable)->str`

You will be given a function as a parameter, the function you are given only accepts two number parameters and produces a float value. It is your job to figure out what mathematical operation the function you are given is performing by passing it many different parameters. The possible operations the function can perform are: add, subtract, multiply, and divide. The given function will only perform a single operation, it will not change after consecutive invocations. The function will execute the operation in the order the parameters are received. You must input your own values and test the expected responses to figure out the operation of the function. Once you have figured it out return the symbol of the operation (+, -, *, /).

Another way to explain what has to happen, your function will receive as a function a parameter lets call it f(x, y), and the output of f(x, y) is z. We know that x and y are numbers and you know that f(x, y) produces z, which is another number. Your job is to create a function that passes different numbers into f and evaluates the output z to find a pattern. The pattern you are looking for is to see if the function f is adding, subtracting, dividing or multiplying x and y. Once you find the pattern your function should return the mathematic symbol (+, -, *, /) that corresponds to function f’s operation. The return value should be a string.

Example:

Input: function

Internally you will do the following

Test:function(1, 1) == 2.0

Test: function(2, 3) == 5.0

Test: function(4,1) == 5.0

Output: '+'

def resultOverrider(x: int, y: int, op: str, override: callable)->int
This function will be given 2 values, x, and y, which will be integers. It will also have two optional values op and override. This function is expected to return an integer. Op will be a string representing a mathematical operation ('+', '-', '*', '/') to be performed between x and y. If op is not defined it should default to addition. Override is a function that accepts two integers and returns an integer as a value. If override is not defined it this function should return the result of x and y computed with the op value or there sum if op is not provided. If override is specified this function should always return the result of the invocation of override with x and y passed into it.

def nestedRemoval(text: str, leftPattern: str, rightPattern: str) -> str
You will be given three strings, the first string is a sentence known as text that contains at least one occurrence of leftPattern and rightPattern. Left pattern and right pattern are single characters strings that you are attempting to remove from the string. Your goal is to remove only the patterns when the left pattern has an equal number of corresponding right patterns. The patterns are removed in pairs only when there is a balanced number of left and right patterns. The patterns may be nested within the text and there is no guarantee that a left pattern will occur before the right pattern.

Example 1:

text = { { Muscat } } { } mecum tollgate } poultry quarrymen pantheon asteria

leftPattern =  {

rightPattern = }

return = Muscat     mecum tollgate } poultry quarrymen pantheon asteria

Example 2:

text = theretofore [ ] [ ] demography ] ] pirouetting morsel [ [ pesticide

leftPattern =  [

rightPattern = ]

return =. demography ] ] pirouetting morsel [ [ pesticide

Example 3:

text = ( castigate ) alfonso ( ) ) ) emitter sourdough ) taco ( schemata

leftPattern =  (

rightPattern = )

return = castigate  alfonso   ) ) emitter sourdough ) Lauren ( schemata

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow!. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Tell us what you have tried, and if you face any problem in a particular we might help, but this is not a place to submit your homeworks/assignments!.

Comment: Can you example of python code, I don't know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem,

```
def productSum(x: int, y: int, z: int) -> int
    if x * y < z:     # Checks if the product of x and y is less than z
        return x * y  # Return the product
    else:
        return x + y  # Else return the sum
```

For your second problem,

```
def functionSolver(function: callable)->str
    if function(2,6) == 8:
        return '+'
    elif function(2,6) == 12:
        return '*'
    elif abs(fucntion(2,6)) == 4:
        return '-'
    elif function(6,2) == 3 || function(2,6) == 3:
        return '/'
```

For your third problem,

```
def resultOverrider(x: int, y: int, op: str = '+', override: callable = None)->int
    if override:
        return override(x, y)
    if op == '+':
        return x + y
    elif op == '-':
        return x - y
    elif op == '*':
        return x * y
    elif op == '/':
        return x / y
```